# Does Using Caching impove the performance of functional programming?

Tags: performance, caching, functional-programming

I have known that functional programming(f.p.) should be return same output for same input.

hence, I think Caching definitely must help f.p. performance.

Is there any exception?

Is is correct? Isn't it?

If I have wrong info, what is the wrong info?

Comment: Caching is always a trade-off between computation power and storage requirements. This doesn't change for functional programming, though of course it's easier to prove the resulting behaviour to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functional programming we call "caching" memoization. It is not automatically a performance enhancement since if your function is O(1) caching it won't improve it. In a way you could way it already is a table lookup so adding another on top won't improve anything.

In some circumstances where it's O(n) or worse and the meomization is hardly used you end up being slower since you are using extra time making a store of called parameters and values that takes more time than recalculating the few cache hits. An example would be the state of a chess game where you hardly revisit the same state so its mostly a wast of memory.

The classic example where memoization shines is the fibonacci sequence:

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 1
f(n) = f(n-2) + f(n-1)
```

Here you visit the same problem many times so memoization will make it from O(n^2) to O(n). If you only use it once then an iterative solution will be better since it does the same without using the extra memory, but if your program uses it more it converges towards O(1).